# Why do 32-bit Steam games on my system use the integrated GPU instead of my dedicated Nvidia card?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, steam, opengl

Native Linux games from Steam work great, except for 32-bit games like Hotline Miami and Team Fortress 2. 64-bit games use my NVIDIA 1060 Max-Q but the 32-bit games use the integrated Intel chip and as a consequence lag a lot. I know that they aren't using the 1060 because the applications do not show up in `nvidia-smi` or `nvtop`.

I've tried a ton of things, but I can't get them to run on my dedicated GPU:

- `primusrun` ./Hotline uses the Intel card
- `__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia %command%` uses the Intel card
- Running the Windows versions with Proton have the same issue. I have also tried running them with Lutris but have had no success

I think the issue is that the 32-bit Nvidia Open-GL libraries are not properly installed, because no 64-bit native Linux game have any issues. I have tried purging and reinstalling the Nvidia drivers, but there is no change.

Running `ldconfig -p | grep GL` gives me this:

```
    libQt5OpenGL.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5OpenGL.so.5
    libQt5OpenGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5OpenGL.so
    libOpenGL.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so.0
    libOpenGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so
    libGLdispatch.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0
    libGLdispatch.so.0 (libc6) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0
    libGLdispatch.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so
    libGLX_nvidia.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_nvidia.so.0
    libGLX_mesa.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_mesa.so.0
    libGLX_mesa.so.0 (libc6) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLX_mesa.so.0
    libGLX.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0
    libGLX.so.0 (libc6) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0
    libGLX.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so
    libGLU.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1
    libGLU.so.1 (libc6) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1
    libGLU.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so
    libGLEW.so.2.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.2.1
    libGLESv2_nvidia.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv2_nvidia.so.2
    libGLESv2.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv2.so.2
    libGLESv2.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv2.so
    libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.1
    libGLESv1_CM.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv1_CM.so.1
    libGLESv1_CM.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLESv1_CM.so
    libGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
    libGL.so.1 (libc6) => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
    libGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
    libEGL_nvidia.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL_nvidia.so.0
    libEGL_mesa.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL_mesa.so.0
    libEGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so.1
    libEGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so
```

Running `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` gives me this:

```
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GTX 1060 with Max-Q Design/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 460.32.03
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 460.32.03
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 460.32.03
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

I'm super stuck on what the issue is and how to fix it. Any help is appreciated.